Difficulties in Axis 1 to Axis 2 Migration progress
I'm currently migrating an Axis 1 SOAP request to an Apache Axis2 SOAP request in a Spring project.
Previously, I used Axis 1 to convert a WSDL file into Java class files. However, in Axis 2, the method names and parameters are significantly different from those generated by Axis 1, making it impossible to reuse the existing Spring code. The Spring code must be modified.
According to the migration documentation (https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/migration.html), it seems there is no straightforward way to migrate, and I may have to rewrite all the SOAP-related code.
**1. Is there an easier way to migrate from Axis 1 to Axis 2 without rewriting the entire code? I believe there might be a solution to simplify this process.
**
2. Is using Apache CXF easier than migrating to Axis2?
tried:

converted wsdl file with axis 2 wsdl2java and modified the code manually previous axis1 spring code. (It works, but I spent so much time)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
